# C++ function pointer (class member) to non-static member function of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have some problem figuring out if it is possible to implement function pointer to non-static member functions to be used within the class itself. I have a simplified code looks like following which works fine where function "func1" is a static member function when the Start function is called:

```
Template<class F> 
class MyClass
{
    public: 
        typedef void (*FuncPtrType)(float*);

        void Start()
        {
            this->Run(Func1);
        }

    protected:
        static void Func1(float arg[]){ // some code }

        void Run(FuncPtrType func){ // some code }
}
```

So my questions if it is even possible to make "func1" non-static? If so, what do I need to do to make it compile. I tried the following code:

```
Template<class F> 
class MyClass
{
    public: 
        typedef void (*FuncPtrType)(float*);

        void Start()
        {
            this->Run(&MyClass<F>::Func1);
        }

    protected:
        void Func1(float arg[]){ // some code }

        void Run(FuncPtrType func){ // some code }
}
```

It is throwing me errors in compilation like: error c2664: ... can not convert from 'void (MyClass::* )(float*)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(float *)'

Comment: ok, considering you haven't found the [c++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html), why do you want to use a pointer to member function instead of just calling the member itself? The class hints at some kind of design of a class hierarchy, would you please elaborate why you need this indirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply change `typedef`.

```
typedef void (MyClass::*FuncPtrType)(float*);
```

Your code doesn't work, since pointer to function != pointer to member-function.